# How to append system date to a filename in perl ?

Tags: perl, date

How to append system date to a filename in perl ?

As i am very new to perl programming , can you give me a simple example for the above query.

Comment: Are you creating new files or do you have existing files to rename? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JustCoder have u tried to R&D the problem yourself. a quick google might help u out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help u out!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $date=`date +%Y%m%d`;
chomp($date);
my $source_file="/tmp/fileName_.tgz";
my $destination_file="/misc/fileName_" . $date . ".tgz";
print "$source_file\n";
print "$destination_file\n";
system("sudo mv /tmp/fileName_.tgz /misc/fileName_$date.tgz");
```

or try this

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
$year += 1900; 

my $out = "$dir/$host-$mday-$mon-$year"
```

or this one

```
# grab the current time
my @now = localtime();

# rearrange the following to suit your stamping needs.
# it currently generates YYYYMMDDhhmmss
my $timeStamp = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", 
                        $now[5]+1900, $now[4]+1, $now[3],
                        $now[2],      $now[1],   $now[0]);

# insert stamp into constant portion of file name.
# the constant portion of the name could be included 
# in the sprintf() above.
my $fileName = "File$timeStamp.log";
```

Comment: Your first example relies on an external program called 'date' and is therefore not portable. Your second example contains a bug (the month will be wrong). All of your examples ignore the existence of POSIX::strftime() which would make this all far easier.

Answer (score 5):

The `strftime()` function from the [POSIX](https://metacpan.org/module/POSIX) module gives an easy way to get a date in whatever format you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $date = strftime '%Y-%m-%d', localtime;
say $date;
```

You can then use  that string in the filename of your file. If you are renaming a file, then you can use `move()` from the [File::Copy](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aCopy) module.